# Write File without deleting current data

Tags: java, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [java append to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369760/java-append-to-file)
> [How to append data to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027764/how-to-append-data-to-a-file)

I want to write a file in java without cleaning(deleting) older data

This is my try, but the current data will be cleaned on writing new data.

```
import java.io.*;

public class WriteToFileExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String content = "New content to write to file";

        File file = new File("/mypath/filename.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-append-content-to-file-in-java/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use constructor [`FileWriter(String filename, boolean append)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) that can instruct the file to be opened in append mode:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                                                     //^^^^ means append
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
```

Notes: second param means append; no need for file.getAbsoluteFile(), just File is OK

Answer (score 3):

open the file in append mode .
like

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfilename", true)));
```

Comment: This will be bit helpfull if you can click on  right sign .

Answer (score 1):

FileWriter takes a boolean argument which specifies whether to overwrite or not.

Try this :

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
```

also visit :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29