# writing to a file and append it each time

Tags: java, file, file-io

I am trying to write some data to the file using the code below

```
private static void writeToFile(String string, String fileFromList) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringBuilder images=new StringBuilder();
    images=images.append(string).append(fileFromList);
    System.out.println("inside database");
    File resultFile = new File("input/phocagallery.tsv");

    BufferedWriter resultWriter = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(resultFile),
                    "UTF-8"));
    resultWriter.write(images.toString());
    resultWriter.close();
}
```

I am calling this function from another loop.. but my problem is that I am getting only one item written into the file.. when a new File object is creating each time when the function call will it create a new file and insert? Why am I getting all the values inserting into the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write File without deleting older data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938886/write-file-without-deleting-older-data), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027764/how-to-append-data-to-a-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369760/java-append-to-file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileOutputStream has a constructor that has a boolean for "append". Set it.